# use zeromq to implement actor model

Tags: model, actor, zeromq

Is there anyone who have implemented actor model using zeromq? how is the performance?
What pattern is used? REQ/REP, PUB/SUB or PUSH/PULL?

I did use another library called theron. But the performance is not quite well due to the context switch.

Is it possible to share your thought/design?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Akka provides a ZeroMQ module which abstracts a ZeroMQ connection and therefore allows interaction between Akka actors to take place over ZeroMQ connections"

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.2/java/zeromq.html